# Как сделать URL без index.php в kohana?

Tags: apache, php, kohana

> http://kohana.loc/index.php/welcome/test

в

> http://kohana.loc/welcome/test

см. .htaccess:

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /kohana

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
# RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Еще вариант, в самом httpd.conf вписать "AllowOverride All" там, где директория прописана, но если я вставляю туда это, т.е.

```
#kohana.loc
<VirtualHost kohana.loc>
AllowOverride All
ServerAdmin mail@mail.ru
ServerName kohana.loc
DocumentRoot "F:/sites/home/kohana.loc/www"
ScriptAlias /cgi/ "F:/sites/home/kohana.loc/cgi/"
ErrorLog F:/sites/home/kohana.loc/error.log
CustomLog F:/sites/home/kohana.loc/access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

т.е. апач вообще не запускается.

примеры логов:

> `[Sat May 12 18:06:08 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: F:/sites/home/kohana.loc/www/welcome
> [Sat May 12 18:07:28 2012] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] F:/sites/home/kohana.loc/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
> [Sat May 12 18:08:04 2012] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] F:/sites/home/kohana.loc/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`

Comment: скорее ответ на форум руткод. Все что ниже предложено до одного места, крутел вертел, выяснилось что модуль modrewrite не подключен, да и AllowOverride All везде нужно ставить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Привет. Попробуй в .htaccess поменять последнюю строчку на:

```
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

А в файле bootstrap.php фреймворка Kohana, код Kohana::init поменяй на:

```
Kohana::init(array(
    'base_url'      => '/',
    'index_file'    => FALSE
));
```

Больше ничего не нужно править и менять. :)

Answer (score 0):

Вот целый видео курс. смотрел помню что там он это решал и очень просто. [Видео-курс](http://www.sdelaysite.com/tag/php)

Answer (score 0):

[Как убрать index.php из адресной строки, используя фреймверк Kohana](http://blog.nagaychenko.com/2010/10/12/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-index-php-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8/).

Answer (score 0):

По памяти, в бустрапе index_url нужно поставить false и все.

Answer (score 0):

У меня сработало вот так:

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/ [PT]
```

Изменил в последней строчке `index.php/$0` на `index.php/`, и все работает!
Ну и `bootstrap.php`, тут все так, как в документации пишут.

```
Kohana::init(array(
    'base_url'   => '/',
    'index_file' => FALSE,
));
```